# Permission denied to access socket - nginx server

Tags: python, sockets, nginx

I have a python application which I am trying to host on NGINX server. I have done following things so far.

1. I have logged in as a user say "user1" and pulled the python source code from git repo.
2. Then I created a ini file as below

   ```
   [uwsgi]
   module = wsgi:app  
   master = true 
   process = 5 
   socket = qbapp.sock 
   chmod-socket    = 666  
   uid = www-data  
   gid = www-data
   logto = /tmp/%n.log
   ```
3. The source code repo and the ini file belongs to the same user 'user1'.
4. Now executed "uwsgi --ini uwsgi_app.ini". This command created a qbapp.sock file

   ```
   srw-rw-rw- 1 user1 user1    0 Oct 12 12:51 qbapp.sock
   ```
5. Now I started the nginx server (configured to python application to run on port 8081)

   My issue is when I tried to access the URL, I am getting 13 permission denied error. From logs

   ```
    connect() to unix:/home/user1/******/******/qbapp.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: bots-admin, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/user1/****/*******/qbapp.sock:", host: "*******.***:8081"
   ```

   According to my investigation having a permissive level of 666 allows the socket to be accessed by nginx

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Make sure that all directories in the path allow access to the user.

Comment: chmod-socket = 664, try this one.

Answer (score -1):

Your user of python app is www-data, and the nginx user is user1.
They are not in same group. so last value of the permission must 6(read and write permission).

Comment: I didn't your last statement about permission.I already have the permission set as 666.Please explain on what you meant by "so last value of the permission must 6"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Is there access permission in your /home/user1/******/******/ ?